# Cuadro latino en Java

Tags: java

Buenas tardes tengo que hacer una aplicación en java que resuelva el cuadro latino usando recursividad.

```
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 2
0 0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Como la verdad no tenia ni idea de como hacer esto, investigue en internet y me encontré con este método que resuelve el cuadro latino.

```
public static void latino (int fila, int col, int cont, int orden, int mat[][])
{
    if (fila == 0 && col == 0)
        mat[0][0] = 1;
    else
        if (fila == col)
           latino (fila - 1, orden - 1, orden, orden, mat);
    else
    {
       mat[fila][col] = cont;
       latino (fila, col - 1, orden + 1, orden, mat);
    }
}
```

Aquí el problema es que no se que parámetros enviar cuando se invoca al método latino desde el main.

Ojala que pudieran ayudarme con esto.

Comment: Imagino que de donde hayas sacado ese código vendría explicado como utilizar ese método. Así a ojo parece ser el tamaño de las filas, columnas, un contador, el orden que deseas y la matriz donde se almacena el resultado.

Comment: No no viene como usarlo, solo pusieron el método

Answer (score 1):

Cómo no puedo ponerte un comentario todavía... te explico aquí varias cosas sobre tu pregunta y tu problema en cuestión.

En primer lugar, tras mirar, analizar y ejecutar varias veces la función que expones en la pregunta, y buscando la fuente de la misma, puedo decir que esa función no realiza un cuadrado latino, ya que no cumple la definición del problema matemático. Además está sesgada parcialmente y no funciona correctamente ya que no controla los casos triviales recursivos de cada parámetro de entrada. En resumen, está mal.

Siendo la definición correcta del problema matemático del cuadrado latino la siguiente:

> Un cuadrado latino es una **matriz** de **n×n** elementos en la que cada casilla está ocupada por uno de los *n* símbolos de tal modo que cada uno de ellos aparece exactamente una vez en cada columna y en cada fila.
>
> [Definición del problema en wikipedia: cuadrado latino](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuadrado_latino)
>
> [Definición en inglés en wikipedia: latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square)

El número de resultados no es único y es por ello que en algunos foros suelen dar como "definición" una de las posibles soluciones. Concretamente he visto en la mayoría de los casos que piden una matriz cuadrada con la que su primera fila contiene los N primeros números naturales y cada una de las siguientes N-1 filas contiene la rotación de la fila anterior un lugar a la derecha*.

Según esta segunda definición (que sí cumple la definición de cuadrado latino), podemos dar varios ejemplos:

```
Cuadrados latinos de orden 3:

1 2 3
3 1 2
2 3 1    

Cuadrado latino de orden 4:

1 2 3 4
4 1 2 3
3 4 1 2
2 3 4 1
```

**Nota:** Evidentemente, puede que en algún momento, el problema haya sido planteado como se ha visto en esos foros, se haya creado una *pequeña* confusión con enunciados de otros problemas y finalmente que se extendiera la solución para el caso particular y propagado como la pólvora como la solución al problema del **cuadrado latino**.